# How to get the ID from combobox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am developing windows application in VS 2010.

application will save name and the batch property.

I have combo-box in which I load the batch list which comes from the database.

While saving the data, I want save the ID of the batch from combo-box item.

How to save the ID when I load the names of the list in combobox ?

Is there any other alternative ?

(AS you can see in the image, when user selects the Batch1/Batch2/Batch3 , instead of selected item's text I want to get the ID.)

[image]

Comment: Show you code to fill combobox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

POst your code ! 
you must get attention to this:

```
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

and

```
 ComboBox1.DataSource = ListOf(ID, Name)
```

Answer (score 1):

See the below sample to fill a combobox

```
connection.Open()
command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
adapter.SelectCommand = command
adapter.Fill(ds)
adapter.Dispose()
command.Dispose()
connection.Close()
ComboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Batch_id"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Batch_Name"
```

to get the `ID` of a selected item in combobox control

```
 Private Sub upadate()
    Dim batchId as Integer
    batchId  = ComboBox1.SelectedValue
   End Sub
```